# Different sizes of SVG icons

Tags: javascript, svg

I don't know why those two svg icons don't have exactly the same size when I'm checking it in the browser.

The first one is:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <path
    d='M10.3333333,16.7141667 L14.88,25.8333333 L51.6666667,25.8333333 L51.6666667,46.5 L10.3333333,46.5 L10.3333333,16.7141667 Z M56.8333333,10.3333333 L46.5,10.3333333 L51.6666667,20.6666667 L43.9166667,20.6666667 L38.75,10.3333333 L33.5833333,10.3333333 L38.75,20.6666667 L31,20.6666667 L25.8333333,10.3333333 L20.6666667,10.3333333 L25.8333333,20.6666667 L18.0833333,20.6666667 L12.9166667,10.3333333 L10.3333333,10.3333333 C7.49166667,10.3333333 5.1925,12.6583333 5.1925,15.5 L5.16666667,46.5 C5.16666667,49.3416667 7.49166667,51.6666667 10.3333333,51.6666667 L51.6666667,51.6666667 C54.5083333,51.6666667 56.8333333,49.3416667 56.8333333,46.5 L56.8333333,10.3333333 Z'
  />
</svg>
```

The second one:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <path
    d='M21,2 L3,2 C1.9,2 1,2.9 1,4 L1,16 C1,17.1 1.9,18 3,18 L10,18 L10,20 L8,20 L8,22 L16,22 L16,20 L14,20 L14,18 L21,18 C22.1,18 23,17.1 23,16 L23,4 C23,2.9 22.1,2 21,2 Z M21,16 L3,16 L3,4 L21,4 L21,16 Z'
  />
</svg>
```

The thing is that I need to have exactly the same viewBox (here 0 0 60 60)for both  but when I'm setting it like this the second icon is much smaller then the first one. I'd like to have them looking the same (size) while having hte same viewBox. What am I missing here?

Comment: Put width and height attributes in svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `width` and `height` atribute but still will not solve the issue

```
    <svg viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="60" height="60">
  <path d="M10.3333333,16.7141667 L14.88,25.8333333 L51.6666667,25.8333333 L51.6666667,46.5 L10.3333333,46.5 L10.3333333,16.7141667 Z M56.8333333,10.3333333 L46.5,10.3333333 L51.6666667,20.6666667 L43.9166667,20.6666667 L38.75,10.3333333 L33.5833333,10.3333333 L38.75,20.6666667 L31,20.6666667 L25.8333333,10.3333333 L20.6666667,10.3333333 L25.8333333,20.6666667 L18.0833333,20.6666667 L12.9166667,10.3333333 L10.3333333,10.3333333 C7.49166667,10.3333333 5.1925,12.6583333 5.1925,15.5 L5.16666667,46.5 C5.16666667,49.3416667 7.49166667,51.6666667 10.3333333,51.6666667 L51.6666667,51.6666667 C54.5083333,51.6666667 56.8333333,49.3416667 56.8333333,46.5 L56.8333333,10.3333333 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

and

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60" width="60" height="60">
  <path d="M21,2 L3,2 C1.9,2 1,2.9 1,4 L1,16 C1,17.1 1.9,18 3,18 L10,18 L10,20 L8,20 L8,22 L16,22 L16,20 L14,20 L14,18 L21,18 C22.1,18 23,17.1 23,16 L23,4 C23,2.9 22.1,2 21,2 Z M21,16 L3,16 L3,4 L21,4 L21,16 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

You can open the svg in ilustrator and fit the path to 60x60px

Comment: Yes, I've just fit it to 60x60 and it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

The second SVG has much more whitespace, and the paths only cover the top-left of the viewbox.

Added borders to show:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="border:solid 1px red">
  <path
    d='M10.3333333,16.7141667 L14.88,25.8333333 L51.6666667,25.8333333 L51.6666667,46.5 L10.3333333,46.5 L10.3333333,16.7141667 Z M56.8333333,10.3333333 L46.5,10.3333333 L51.6666667,20.6666667 L43.9166667,20.6666667 L38.75,10.3333333 L33.5833333,10.3333333 L38.75,20.6666667 L31,20.6666667 L25.8333333,10.3333333 L20.6666667,10.3333333 L25.8333333,20.6666667 L18.0833333,20.6666667 L12.9166667,10.3333333 L10.3333333,10.3333333 C7.49166667,10.3333333 5.1925,12.6583333 5.1925,15.5 L5.16666667,46.5 C5.16666667,49.3416667 7.49166667,51.6666667 10.3333333,51.6666667 L51.6666667,51.6666667 C54.5083333,51.6666667 56.8333333,49.3416667 56.8333333,46.5 L56.8333333,10.3333333 Z'
  />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="border:solid 1px red">
  <path
    d='M21,2 L3,2 C1.9,2 1,2.9 1,4 L1,16 C1,17.1 1.9,18 3,18 L10,18 L10,20 L8,20 L8,22 L16,22 L16,20 L14,20 L14,18 L21,18 C22.1,18 23,17.1 23,16 L23,4 C23,2.9 22.1,2 21,2 Z M21,16 L3,16 L3,4 L21,4 L21,16 Z'
  />
</svg>
```

You can either:

- Reduce the viewbox down to its ~ 25x25 viewbox and style the height/width using HTML/CSS instead
- edit the SVG and have it fill a 60x60 viewbox